# smart diagram in latex

Tags: smartdiagram

I have some problems with my generated diagram using smart diagram package in beamer class. You can see the considered code as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,calc,mindmap,trees,arrows,chains}
\RequirePackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{General Settings 1}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \smartdiagramset{%
    uniform color list=blue for 3 items,
    back arrow disabled=true,
  module minimum width=2cm,
  module minimum height=1.5cm,
  arrow line width=5pt,
  module x sep=4cm,
  text width=2.5cm,
  additions={
    additional item offset=0.8cm,
    additional item border color=red,
    additional arrow color=red,
    additional item width=2.25cm,
    additional item height=1cm,
    additional item text width=2cm,
    additional arrow line width=5pt,
    additional item bottom color=red!50,
    additional item shadow=drop shadow,
  }
}
\smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]{
\textbf{Mining of ore}\\ \scriptsize{(underground or open-cut mining)}, \textbf{Processing of ore}\\ \scriptsize{(crushing, grinding, flotation)},  \textbf{Mineral product}
}{below of module1/Waste rock,above of module2/Process water, below of module2/Tailings to tailings dam}
\smartdiagramconnect{<-}{module2/additional-module2}
\smartdiagramconnect{<-}{additional-module1/module1}
\smartdiagramconnect{<-}{additional-module3/module2}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The resulted diagram is something like this:
[image: Text]

However, I like to generate the following diagram:
[image: Text]

There are three issues in this regard:

1- The arrows are not shaded,

2- The text in additional boxes cannot be typed in bold or smaller fonts,

3- The blocks cannot be different in their size or colors.

So, is anybody eager to help me to solve the problems?
Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: use plain tikz instead of smartdiagram -- which is inflexible after some extent

Comment: Thanks, Bibra, It's still a bit hard for me to set the configuration in tikz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As  starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning
                }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{General Settings 1}
    \begin{figure}
\tikzset{
every edge/.style = {draw=cyan, line width=2mm, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt,
                     -{Triangle[scale=0.6]}},
N/.style args = {#1/#2}{fill=#1, text width=#2, 
                        font=\scriptsize, align=center},
   N/.default = cyan/7em,
}
\newcommand\tn[1]{\textbf{\small #1}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=8mm]
\node (n1) [N]  {\tn{Mining of ore}\\ 
                 (underground or open-cut mining)}; 
\node (n2) [N=cyan/8em, right=of n1] 
                {\tn{Processing of ore}\\ 
                 (crushing, grinding, flotation)};
\node (n3) [N, right=of n2] 
                {\tn{Mineral product}};
\node (n4) [N, below=of n1]
                {\tn{Waste rock}};
\node (n5) [N=red!30/8em, below=of n2]
                {\tn{Tailings to tailings dam}};
\node (n6) [N=cyan/8em, above=of n2]
                {\tn{Process watter}
                 (from desalination plants, lakes, boreholes,
                  rivers, or other sources)};
\draw   (n1) edge (n2)
        (n2) edge (n3)
        (n1) edge (n4)
        (n2) edge (n5)
        (n2) edge (n6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hats-off to you.